# Array to excel React

Tags: reactjs

I am a little new to this, I am trying to pass my data array to an excel, but nothing works for me so far

I have an example

```
import {ExcelFile, ExcelSheet} from "react-export-excel";

const [listSelectNewTable, setListSelectNewTable] = useState([])

const DataExcel = [
{
columns: [
  { value: "Clave Cliente", widthPx: 50 }, 
  { value: "Nobre Cliente", widthCh: 20, widthCh: 20  }, 
  { value: "Clave Articulo", widthPx: 60}, 
  { value: "Nombre Cliente", widthPx: 60}, 
  { value: "Clave Unidad", widthPx: 60},
  { value: "Precio", widthPx: 60}, 
],
data: [listSelectNewTable],
}
];

class Download extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <ExcelFile>
            <ExcelSheet dataSet={DataExcel} name="Price"/>
        </ExcelFile>
    );
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share which library you are using (e.g. what the ExcelFile and ExcelSheet are)?

Comment: ready add it...

Comment: Have you tried with this example dataset? If yes then the data you provide is not in the right format - https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/HEAD/examples/simple_excel_export_02.md

Comment: Your `data` array you are passing to the `dataSet` prop does not contain any data (?) Furthermore it's of incorrect type. It's supposed to be [`Array<ExcelCellData>`](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/master/types/types.md) meanwhile you are passing `Array<Array<never>>`

Comment: If it is the example that I am taking, to make myself understand better, I just want to pass 
`const [listSelectNewTable, setListSelectNewTable] = useState([])` to an excel .. How do I do this? or where can I take an example

Answer (score 0):

#### Before we begin:

> Well obviously you're not going to have any data, if you're not passing any to the `dataSet`:
>
> ```js
> const [listSelectNewTable, setListSelectNewTable] = useState([])
>
> // listSelectNewTable = []
> ```

Also you are attempting to call `useState` outside of a [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) component and then proceed to use a `class` component later down the line. Without meaning to sound condescending, you really should study up on when to use [life-cycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and when to use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) *(hint: it's either one or the other)*, because it's outside of the scope of this question / answer, but your code will never work if you don't put the time in to at least understand the basics.

The remainder of my answer assumes you at least fixed that.

#### The Problem:

Furthermore, even if it had any data, it would result in an error, because **your data is incorrectly typed**:

The `dataSet` prop `type` is defined as:

```
dataSet: Array<ExcelSheetData>
```

considering the [following package type definitions](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/master/types/types.md):

```
interface ExcelSheetData {
    xSteps?: number;
    ySteps?: number;
    columns: Array<string>;
    data: Array<ExcelCellData>;
}

type ExcelCellData = ExcelValue | ExcelCell;
type ExcelValue = string | number | Date | boolean;

interface ExcelCell {
    value: ExcelCell;
    // [Note]: this is actually incorrectly typed in the package itself.
    // Should be value: ExcelCellValue instead
    style: ExcelStyle;
}
```

Essentially, if you had [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) enabled *(which by the way I'd advise you to do)*, you'd see you're attempting to pass incorrect data-type to the `dataSet` property.

- What you should be passing to `dataSet` prop is

  ```
   Array<ExcellCellData>
   // expecting: Array<ExcelValue | ExcelCell> (eg. ['A', 22])
  ```
- What you are actually passing to to `dataSet` prop is

  ```
   Array<Array<never>>
   // received: [[]]
   // [] = Array<never>
  ```

As you can see, the `Array<Array<>>` wraps it twice, meaning you are passing an unnecessarily wrapped array there.

#### Solution:

Now that we know the cause, let's fix it:

```js
const DataExcel = [
 {
  columns: [
    { value: "Clave Cliente", widthPx: 50 }, 
    { value: "Nobre Cliente", widthCh: 20, widthCh: 20  }, 
    { value: "Clave Articulo", widthPx: 60}, 
    { value: "Nombre Cliente", widthPx: 60}, 
    { value: "Clave Unidad", widthPx: 60},
    { value: "Precio", widthPx: 60}, 
  ],
  data: listSelectNewTable, // previously was [listSelectNewTable]
  // Note we removed the extra wrapping nested array [] ˆ
 },
];
```

Now you are passing your data correctly - but obviously you're not going to have anything inside the excel sheet barring the columns unless you pass any actual data instead of the empty array.

#### Final note (not necessary for answer):

Also in general I'd recommend using packages that have higher star ratings on their github page *(this one has 65)* and is only a fork of a an already existing package, especially for more complex stuff like excel exporting. While there sometimes truly are hidden diamonds in the rough, most of the time the stars are a good indicator of the quality of the package.

The fact that I found a typing error inside my own answer after a random glance at the package for the first time makes me fear how many other errors are actually in it, unless you know and trust the author or it's a package for a very niche thing.

Because the recursive

```
 interface ExcelCell {
   value: ExcelCell; // should be ExcelCellValue
   style: ExcelStyle;
 }
```

makes positively no sense and would just require you to recursively state the object interface definition ad infinitum

Comment: `listSelectNewTable`It already comes with data, I fill it with another method, now as I add it to an object that my task is to create the excel and then send it through S3